# Can the DNS-server in FiOS-provided Actiontec router offer SRV-records?

Tags: dns, fios

I'm trying to teach my iOS-devices to print onto the LAN-connected printer here. [The manual](http://sybaspot.com/configuring-dns-to-share-bonjour-printers-across-subnets-and-vlans-including-airprint-for-ios/) calls for adding certain DNS-records.

On my LAN the FiOS-provided Actiontec-router is providing the DNS-service. Unfortunately, it *seems* to only offer A- and PTR-records -- the interface lets you specify hostname and IP-address. No SRV-records, nor any other types.

Is my impression correct, or is there some "sneaky" way to add the missing information? I really don't want to stand up a separate DNS-server over this...

Thank you!